# HTML 5 chartjs not working as static file

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am trying to use the [chartjs](https://www.chartjs.org/) to draw charts using HTML5. Does it not work if I open the HTML file by right-clicking on it and open in google chrome. I am seeing a blank screen for the following code:

```
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"/>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
<body>
<div style="width:75%;">
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I doing something wrong in code or do I need a server(eg. apache) to run the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were basically two problems:

1. `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js" />` is not a valid script. It should be `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>`
2. Your second script must be loaded once HTML/DOM is rendered. `getContext ()` was not able to find `canvas` id.

Below is working example:

```html
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>


<body>
  <div style="width:75%;">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: If rendering using server side scripting (e.g. PHP), you could just insert the javascript file contents within <script></script> tags, so the page is totally static and self-contained.
e.g.:
<script>
<?php
include_once("{path to local version of chart.js}");
?>
</script>

or perhaps use curl to go to the web and get the script contents then simply echo them within the tags.
Then your script would be fully self-contained.